# Can I write the Geometric algebra product as a tensor product ? How are they related?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

The geometric algebra product of two vectors $v$ and $w$

$ v w = v \cdot w + v \wedge w $ is defined to be
$ vw = 1/2 (vw +wv) + 1/2 ( vw- wv) $.

The Wedge product in differential geometry is defined as follows
$
 \vec{v} \wedge \vec{w}
 =
 \vec{v} \otimes \vec{w} - \vec{w} \otimes \vec{v}
$

Except for the factor $1/2$, which could be a definition matter, the wedge product of two vectors in geometry algebra language and the wegde product in differential geometry language seem to be the same. Can I relate the GA product with the tensor product ? Can I interpret the inner product as a symmetric tensor product
$
 \vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}
 =
 \vec{v} \otimes \vec{w} + \vec{w} \otimes \vec{v}
$
It seems like I would need
$
 \vec{v} \cdot \vec{w}
 =
 1/2\text{Tr}(\vec{v} \otimes \vec{w} + \vec{w} \otimes \vec{v})
$.

Does anyone knows how this works or have a good source for me to learn ?

Comment: I'm a physicist with only a bachelor degree in math, so simple examples are great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Geometric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra) (GA) is really just a [Clifford algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra), i.e. it is basically a [tensor algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_algebra) with an equivalence relation.

The product of two vectors $v$ and $w,$ written $vw,$ is defined as $v\otimes w$ with the extra condition that $v^2 := vv = |v|^2.$

The inner product (dot product) of two vectors is defined as
$$v\cdot w = \frac12(vw+wv) = \frac12(v\otimes w + w\otimes v),$$
and the exterior product as
$$v\wedge w = \frac12(vw-wv) = \frac12(v\otimes w - w\otimes v).$$

The [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) of differential geometry is closely related. It is spanned by all antisymmetric elements in the tensor algebra, like $v\wedge w$ above and
$$
u\wedge v\wedge w = \frac16(u\otimes v\otimes w - u\otimes w\otimes v + w\otimes u\otimes v - w \otimes v\otimes u + v\otimes w\otimes u - v\otimes u\otimes w).
$$

The linked pages on Wikipedia have quite a lot of information.

Comment: You claim$$v\cdot w = \frac12(vw+wv) = \frac12(v\otimes w + w\otimes v),$$, but  since $$
 \vec{v} \otimes \vec{w}
  =
 ( v_1 e_1 + v_2 e_2 ) \otimes ( w_1 e_1 + w_2 e_2 ) 
 \\
 =
  v_1 w_1 e_1   \otimes e_1 +  v_1 w_2 e_1   \otimes e_2 + v_2 w_1 e_2   \otimes e_1 + v_2 w_2 e_2   \otimes e_2
  \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix}
        v_1 w_1   &    v_1 w_2    \\
        v_2 w_1   &   v_2 w_2 e_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$\frac{1}{2}(v\otimes w + w\otimes v) = $ \begin{pmatrix}
        2 v_1 w_1   &    v_1 w_2  + v_2 w_1    \\
        v_1 w_2  + v_2 w_1    &  2 v_2 w_2 e_2
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Question: How is $\frac{1}{2}(v\otimes w + w\otimes v) = $ \begin{pmatrix}
        2 v_1 w_1   &    v_1 w_2  + v_2 w_1    \\
        v_1 w_2  + v_2 w_1    &  2 v_2 w_2 e_2
\end{pmatrix} equal to $v \cdot w$ ?

Comment: Note that GA is not plain tensor algebra but one a quotient algebra of tensor algebra with respect to the equivalence relation $v\otimes v=|v|^2 \mathbf{1}.$ This equivalence relation makes $e_1\otimes e_1$ and $e_2\otimes e_2$ both reduce to the unit element $\mathbf{1}.$ Also, $e_1 \otimes e_2 = - e_2\otimes e_1.$ Therefore $v\otimes w + w\otimes v$ reduces to $v_1 w_1 + v_2 w_2.$

Comment: By the way, you have an erroneous $e_2$ in your matrices. It shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out ! I will read more over and study the links !